# what does mean a 'get' statement in a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What does mean 'get' inside a javascript function?. This 'get' is used many time in the return. I stumbled upon this code:

```
var getHost = function () {
    return {
        get linux() {
            return process.platform === 'linux';
        },
        get windows() {
            return process.platform === 'win32';
        },
        get mac() {
            return process.platform === 'darwin';
        },
    };
};
```

Return value is `{ linux: [Getter], windows: [Getter], mac: [Getter] }`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: @MarcB thank you. I read it and it is clear thanks again